# Prevent signal to propagate to child process

Tags: php, unix, process, background-process

I have a script toto1.php which call an other script toto2.php in background.

**toto1.php**

```
$command = 'nohup php toto2.php > /dev/null 2> /dev/null &';
exec($command);
while (true) {
    echo "sleep...\n";
    sleep(1);
}
```

**toto2.php**

```
<?php
function signalHandler($signal)
{
    echo "SIGNAL: $signal\n";
    exit;
}
pcntl_signal(SIGINT, 'signalHandler');

for ($i = 0;;$i++) {
    pcntl_signal_dispatch();
    echo "HELLO $i\n";
    sleep(1);
}
```

When I launch `toto1.php` on a terminal and kill it with `ctrl+c`, a `SIGINT` signal is sent to `toto2.php`. How can I prevent `toto1.php` to send signal to `toto2.php` when it is killed?

Regards

Comment: If you have a typical Linux distro, try using `setsid` instead of `nohup` and let us know if it helps.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick It worked, thank you!

Comment: Good. If no one answers with an all-php solution, I'll post the setsid answer.